# Concurrent Access From Multiple Processes to Single Sql Server Compact Database File

Tags: sql-server-ce

My understanding is that Sql Server compact is intended to be a data store for single application that runs in-process. It is OK for two different processes to connect to and access data from the same .sdf file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

> SQL Server Compact supports multiple connections up to the 256
>   connection limit. Opening connections on different processes is also
>   supported.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645984%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).